# Is it possible to reset group_by items of a sqlalchemy query object in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a `sqlalchemy` query object which contains some `group_by` items added earlier using the `query.group_by()` method. I want to reset those items and add new `group_by` items. Is it possible? If so then please find me the way.

Comment: Please don't just down vote :-( Add a reason too.

Comment: you need to Update code What you tried @ you aim . By the way Iam not the One Down Voted . Improve your Post with some code there may be chances od getting Up votes too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group_by` columns are stored in `_group_by` property of the `query` object. You can set it to `False` or empty list `[]`:

```
query._group_by = False
```

or

```
query._group_by = []
```

Comment: Is this a documented feature? Is there any kind of guarantee that this code will work with future versions of sqlalchemy?

Comment: @g.a I didn't find this in the documentation, there is no guarantee